# How to find a line that minimizes the average squared perpendicular distance from the given points to the line?

Tags: optimization, vectors, data-analysis, least-squares

I have set of points scattered around the origin. How to find a vector, such that the average squared distance (perpendicular distance) from points to the vector is minimised?

#### Added

For example, let the dimension   be 2. So a vector can be written (from the origin) as $(a_1,a_2)$. Now take a point $(x_1, x_2)$. Drop a perpendicular line from the point to the vector and I want to find the length of that line segment.

Comment: What do you mean by the distance from a point to a vector?

Comment: Let the dimension to be 2. So a vector can be written (from the origin) as (a1,a2). Now take a point (x1, x2). Drop a perpendicular line from the point to the vector and I want to find the length of that line segment.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past.
The key is to write the line in *polar* form
(one reference is here:
http://www.robertobigoni.eu/Matematica/Lines/lines08/lines08.html
).

In this form,
the parameters are 
the distance of the line from the origin
and the angle the line
makes with the X axis.

The advantage of this form of the line
is that the distance from any point
to the line
is easily computed.

It turns out that the line which minimizes 
the sum of squares
of the distances from the points
to the line
passes through the centroid of the data points.
Of all the lines which do this,
there are two 
for which the derivative
of the sum of squares of the distances
is zero -
one which minimizes the sum of squares
(which is the one you want)
and one,
which is orthogonal to the first,
which maximizes the sum of squares.

It turns out that
this can me derived
without any calculus.

I'll see if I can resurrect
my results,
but this might be a good start.

---

OK, I found it.

Here is what I wrote,
after converting from $\LaTeX$
to MathJax:

There are a number of forms
that the equation of
a straight line can take
(e.g.,
point-slope, intersection with axes,
$y~=~mx+b$).
The form most useful
for our purpose
is the $polar$ form.
In this form,
a line $L$
is determined by
its distance r from the origin
and the angle $\theta$
that the normal from the origin 
to the line
makes with the $x$ axis, 
the angle being measured
counterclockwise.

---

The equation of $L$
in terms of r and $\theta$
is
$$L:~~     
x\cos \theta + y \sin \theta ~=~r.$$

This can be verified
by noting that 
$x~=~r/\cos\theta$ at $y~=~0$
and
$y~=~r/\sin\theta$ at $x~=~0$.

Another derivation
of equation (1) for $L$
is as follows:

Let $(x,y)$ be a point on $L$,
$d$ the distance of
$(x,y)$ from the origin,
and $\phi$ the angle
that the line from the origin
to $(x, y)$
makes with the $x$-axis.
The angle between this line
and the normal to $L$
is easily seen to be
$\theta-\phi$.
Thus,
$r/d ~=~\cos(\theta-\phi)$.
Since
$x~=~d\cos \phi$
and $y~=~d\sin \phi$,
$
x \cos \theta + y \sin \theta
= d \cos (\theta-\phi)
= r.
$

This derivation,
though more complicated than
the preceding one,
has the advantage of
also giving explicit formulae
for $x$ and $y$
in terms of $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$,
$x~=~{r\cos\phi \over \cos(\theta-\phi)}$
and
$y~=~{r\sin\phi \over \cos(\theta-\phi)}.$

The polar form for
the equation of $L$
is so useful
because
the distance from
any point $(u, v)$
to $L$
is $u\cos \theta + v \sin \theta - r$.
To show this,
consider the line $L'$
through $(u, v)$
that is parallel to $L$.
If $d$ is the distance
from $L'$ to $L$,
which is also the distance 
from $(u, v)$ to $L$,
the equation of $L'$ is
$x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta~=~d+r$,
since $L$ and $L'$ are parallel.
Since $(u, v)$ is on $L'$, 
$u\cos\theta+v\sin\theta~=~d+r$,
so that,
as claimed,
$d~=~u\cos\theta+y\sin\theta-r$.

Evaluating the mean squared error

We now define some 
notation and abbreviations.

Let $c~=~\cos \theta$ and
$s~=~\sin \theta$,
so the equation of $L$ is
$cx+sy~=~r$.
The data points
used to fit $L$
are $(x_i, y_i)$
for $i=1$ to $n$
(i.e., 
there are $n$ points).
For any expression f,
we define $mean(f)$
to be the average of f
over all the data points,
so that
$$mean(f) ~=~(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n f_i.$$

For example,
$mean(x) ~=~(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$,
and
$mean(xy) ~=~(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$.

Note:
We can also define
$mean(f) $
to be a weighted mean
$$mean(f) ~=~{\sum_{i=1}^n f_i w_i \over \sum_{i=1}^n w_i}$$
where each $w_i > 0$,
and the results which follow
are not affected at all.

If $p$ and $q$ are any of $x$ and $y$, 
we define the covariance 
between the variables $p$ and $q$
to be 
$$cov(p,q)~=~mean(pq) -mean(p) mean(q).$$

For example,
$cov(x,x)~=~mean(x^2)-mean(x)^2$
and
$cov(x,y)=mean(xy)-mean(x)mean(y).$

If D is the mean squared error 
of $L$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
D 
&= mean((distance\ from\ point\ i to\ L)^2\\
&= mean(d^2)\\
&= mean((cx+sy-r)^2) \\
&= mean(c^2x^2+s^2y^2+r^2 +
2csxy-2crx-2sry) \\
&=~ c^2\ mean(x^2) +s^2\ mean(y^2) +r^2+
2sc\ mean(xy) -2cr\ mean(x) -2sr\ mean(y)\\
\end{array}
$

Minimizing the mean squared error

If $L$ is to be  the best fitting line
in the least mean squared sense,
we must have
${\partial D \over \partial r}~=~0$
and
${\partial D \over \partial \theta}~=~0.$

However,
the values of $r$ and $\theta$
that minimize $D$
can be found without using any calculus.
This will now be done
by writing $D$
as the sum of terms which,
when independently minimized,
give the desired values
for $r$ and $\theta$.

$$\eqalignno{
D~&=~ c^2\ mean(x^2) +s^2\ mean(y^2) +r^2+
2sc\ mean(xy) -2cr\ mean(x) -2sr\ mean(y)\cr
&=~ c^2\ mean(x^2) +s^2\ mean(y^2) +2sc\ mean(xy)
+r^2 -2r(c\ mean(x) +s\ mean(y))\cr
&=~ c^2\ mean(x^2) +s^2\ mean(y^2) +2sc\ mean(xy)
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2
-(c\ mean(x) +s\ mean(y))^2\cr
&=~c^2(mean(x^2)-mean(x)^2) 
+ s^2(mean(y^2)-mean(y)^2)
 + 2sc(mean(xy)-mean(x)mean(y))
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2\cr
&=~c^2 cov(x,x) + s^2 cov(y,y)+2sc\ cov(x,y)
 +(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2.\cr
}$$

Letting $S=\sin 2\theta =2sc$
and $C=\cos 2\theta=c^2-s^2$,
since
$c^2=(1+C)/2$ and
$s^2=(1-C)/2$,
$$\eqalignno{
D~&=~{cov(x,x)+cov(y,y) \over 2}
+ C {cov(x,x)-cov(x,y) \over 2}
 + S cov(x,y)
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2\cr
&=~D_1+C~D_2+S~D_3
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2\cr
}$$
where
$
D_1=~{cov(x,x) +cov(y,y) \over 2},
$
$
D_2=~{cov{x,x} -cov{y,y} \over 2},
$
and
$
D_3~=~cov(x,y)
$.

Defining $R$ and $\phi$ by
$D_2~=~R\cos\phi$
and
$D_3~=~R\sin\phi$
where
$R \ge 0$
and
$0 \le \phi < 2\pi$,
$$\eqalignno{
D~&=~D_1+C~D_2+S~D_3
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2\cr
&=~D_1+R\cos 2\theta\cos\phi+R\sin 2\theta\sin\phi
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2\cr
&=~D_1+R\cos(2\theta-\phi)
+(r-c\ mean(x) -s\ mean(y))^2.\cr
}$$
This is the desired
expression for $D$.

Since
$\cos(2\theta-\phi) \ge -1$
and
$(r-c mean(x)-s mean(y))^2 \ge 0$,
$D \ge D_1-R$.
By choosing
$$\theta~=~{\phi+\pi \over 2}
\ {\text and}\ 
r~=~mean(x)\cos\theta + mean(y)\sin\theta,$$
$D$ will achieve its minimum value
$$D~=~D_1 - R.$$

Comment: I assume the direction of the line is an eigenvector of the matrix $\sum_i (x_i-\bar x)(x_i-\bar x)^T$, where $\bar x$ is the aforementioned centroid? *Edit:* Actually, the question asks for a line which passes through the origin, in which case it should just be $\sum_i x_i x_i^T$, and the centroid is not relevant.

Comment: [Deming regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) article has the solution for 2D case, but their version of total least squares does not require the line to pass through the origin, which appears to be the case here... One approach I found on the web was to double the data set, throwing in the central  reflection of every point. This forces the centroid to be at the origin. And the contributions of symmetric points to the TLS error are the same, anyway. cc @Rahul

Comment: @Rahul So, this is just the first component of [Principal component analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis). Sounded familiar.

Comment: This does *not* require the line to pass through the origin. That only happens when $r=0$, which happens when the mean of the data points is the origin.

Comment: The link in your answer seems to point to something unrelated. Perhaps this is a case of link rot and you may include intended content in the answer and remove the link.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand the question, this is the problem of fitting with perpendicular offsets.

In case of 2D. :
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPerpendicularOffsets.html

In case of 3D. , see pages 2-12 in section "3D Linear Regression" of the paper : 
http://fr.scribd.com/doc/31477970/Regressions-et-trajectoires-3D